# Which one of Vedas has referred to Dhyanalinga consecrated by Sadhguru?

Tags: vedas, shiva, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga, sadhguru-jaggi-vasudev

In [*Sadhguru More Than A Life*](https://archive.org/details/SadhguruMoreThanALifeArundhatiSubramaniamPenguin_201803/page/n141/mode/2up), one of his disciples mentioned a priest in Trichy mentioning Dhyanalinga is consecrated by a Grihasta Yogi, and he remembers reading about this in one of the Vedas. Does anybody know which one it is?

Comment: Do you mean which Veda mentions Dhyanalinga?

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it is mentioned in the Rig Veda.

From the book [*Mystic's Musings*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vJanDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT519&lpg=PT519&dq=dhyanalingam+vedas+grihastha+yogi&source=bl&ots=cyRK8xPJpF&sig=ACfU3U0uHs4yFfyBzeKN0ovubcZiudkF4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih_LWsq8D0AhWWTGwGHWLxCqYQ6AF6BAgREAM#v=onepage&q=dhyanalingam%20vedas%20grihastha%20yogi&f=false) by Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev:

> **SEEKER: Sadhguru, has anything ever been written about the science of creating a Dhyanalinga?**
>
> **Sadhguru:** Nowhere really, except it finds mention in just one sentence in the Rig Veda, where it says that the Dhyanalinga will be successfully created only by a grihastha yogi. Any number of yogis have attempted this, but it didn't happen.

Comment: Where in Rigveda?

Comment: @Kanthri No idea: it’s consistently mentioned to be a very obscure reference, so you’ll have to find a very learned scholar to try and get an exact reference.

Comment: Thanks. I doubt it. Most of Sadguru's statements are vague. I had come across couple on Mahabharata which I am sure is not in Vyasa Bharata.